# How do I get data of nuclear mass of each nuclide?

Tags: nuclear-physics

I have been searching for a table of **nuclear mass** for a long time, but what I got are mostly data of **atomic mass**. The mass of electrons and the atomic binding energy might bring error to the calculation involving nuclear mass.

Comment: What are you looking that you didn't find using a search for $nuclide$ $mass$ ?  For example https://nds.iaea.org/relnsd/vcharthtml/VChartHTML.html

Comment: @DrChuck Thank you very much. However it seems that I have to calculate the nuclear mass using the binding energy data and tabulate them, instead of getting the experimental data directly.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/576944/44126, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/415341/44126, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186897/44126

Answer (score 0):

You need a chart of the nuclides which you can access on line. There used to be posters of this but i don't know if its still sold. [LiveChart](https://nds.iaea.org/relnsd/vcharthtml/VChartHTML.html) has an interactive display and Wikipedia has a chart on their web site but it doesn't have your data included. The chart on Wikipedia is not complete but gives you an idea of how big the Chart of the Nuclides is. There is a very useful chart [here](https://people.physics.anu.edu.au/%7Eecs103/chart/) that appears to be complete. You can scroll in and out looking for a nucleus. Once you find one you want you can click on the square and it lists a large amount of data for each nucleus.  There are literally thousands of nuclides.

Comment: Note that both of those links seems to be displaying data from the ENSDF/NNDC, whose [definitions of mass, mass excess, and binding energy](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/nudat2/help/glossary.jsp#mass) seem to lump nuclear and electronic binding energy together. The total electronic binding energy is quite significant for large-$Z$ nuclei.