# Why aren't electrons accounted for when calculating the energy of nuclear decay?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation

In my physics exercises, I had to calculate the energy generated by the decay of an atom of the isotope 40 of K by Beta - decay.

It gives us the products: isotope 40 of Calcium and one electron.

When calculating the energy generated, using $Q = \Delta m * c^2$, I ended up with the wrong answer. However, when I didn't account for the electron in the $\Delta m$, I got the right answer.

Why isn't the electron accounted for in this reaction?

Comment: It would probably help more if you write out the problem statement and what you did as a calculation. But most likely you should ask the person giving these problems.

Comment: They are accounted for. Your data source is probably neutral atomic masses rather than bare nuclear masses. See e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/695775/44126 or https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/577005/44126

Comment: @rob Thank you so much! You can post this reply has an answer and I will accept it. :)